# How to clear EditText input from all item views of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am looking for solution to iterate over all views of my Recycler View Adapter elements to get EditTexts and change inputs.

I use RecyclerView list. Item rows contain EditText. When user clicks a button, I want to clear inputs of all item views, even those not bound yet. How should I do that?

```
class ScoresAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ScoresViewHolder>() {

private var scores: List<Score> = ArrayList()
private var listener: ScoreItemListener? = null

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ScoresViewHolder {
    val view =
        LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.score_item, parent, false)

    return ScoresViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return scores.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ScoresViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val score = scores[position]

    holder.playerView.text = score.player.email
    holder.totalScoreView.text = score.total().toString()
}

fun setItemListener(listener: ScoreItemListener) {
    this.listener = listener
}

fun loadScores(scores: ArrayList<Score>) {
    this.scores = scores
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun clearInputs() {
    // for all scores in list remove text from EditText and set ""
}

inner class ScoresViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var playerView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.player)!!
    var currentScoreView = itemView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.current_score)!!
    var totalScoreView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.total_score)!!

    init {
        setTextChangedListener(itemView)
    }

    private fun setTextChangedListener(itemView: View) {
        if (listener != null)
            currentScoreView.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

                }

                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

                }

                override fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                    listener!!.textChanged(itemView, text!!.toString(), adapterPosition)
                }

            })
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried with `your_edittext.text = "" or your_edittext.setText("")` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like below ::

```
var clearEditText = false

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ScoresViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val score = scores[position]

    holder.playerView.text = if(clearEditText) "" else score.player.email
    holder.totalScoreView.text = score.total().toString()
}


fun clearInputs() {
    clearEditText = true
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: how this function will be called sir ? i think it needs any listener like clear button ?

Comment: On button click just call from your activity or fragment : `adapter.clearInputs()` where the adapter is an instance of your recyclerview adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you might have to save `EditText` input as `currentScore` in `Score` later.

Assuming this and  `currentScore` as `String`.

In java:

```
public void clearInputs() {
 for(Score score: scores) {
  score.currentScore = "";
 }
 notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

in Kotlin:

```
fun clearInputs() {
  for (score in scores)
  {
    score.currentScore = ""
  }
  notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this it might work

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ScoresViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val score = scores[position]

    holder.playerView.text = if(clearEditText) "" else score.player.email
    holder.totalScoreView.text = score.total().toString()
    holder.currentScoreView.setText("")
}

public void clearInputs() {
 notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: There is minor issues with you're code you haven't set `Boolean` value to `clearEditText` so how come if condition pick that up ?